# Introductive Book on Modular Forms

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms

I'm looking for an introductive book on Modular Forms and their applications to Algebraic Geometry and Algebraic Number Theory.

Some Ideas?

Explaining you my prerequisites, I've a good knowledge of basic instruments of Algebra and Algebraic Geometry, but I need some explanations in geometrical facts about Riemann Surfaces and Advanced Complex Analysis...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first book you want to look at is Serre's "A course in arithmetic". THe second is the aptly named ["A first course in modular forms"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/038723229X)

Comment: Thank you! Another related question: in this books there's something about the J-invariants? Do you have some references about them?

Comment: Yes. Serre's book already talks about it (I think), and certainly Diamond does.

Comment: "The second is the aptly named 'A first course in modular forms'" -- that made me smile, although I wholly agree with the recommendations!

Answer (score 7):

Step $0$: J W Brown & R V Churchill - Complex Variables and Applications [[→]](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0073383171);

Step $\frac12$: E Freitag & R Busam : Complex Analysis [[→]](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540939825);

Step $1$: E Freitag - Complex Analysis 2 [[→]](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642205538).

Answer (score 3):

The book---"A first course in modular forms" by F. Diamond, J. Shurman is a good book to start to study classical modular forms. The advanced one--- "Modular forms" by Toshitsune Miyake is also a very good textbook to learn modular forms. Good luck.

Comment: Velcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

**Modular Forms A Classical Approach**, by Henri Cohen and Fredrik Strömberg.

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/0821849476](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0821849476)

A recent book ( 2017 ) with lots of exercises, only prerequisite is complex analysis.